# Network error. The request timed out in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, react-apollo

my react app was working fine on localhost but
after build react app and upload it on my server it doesnt work and this is what i get
[image]

I think it doesnt connect to graphql and mongodb
and this is my dependencies
[image]

what should I do?

edit:
i changed URIs in code to my host and I dont know where's my problem
[image][image]

in localhost I start server every time with npm run dev is there any chance that i have start app in server too?

Comment: Make sure it can connect to your GraphQL and MongoDB. Did you provide the correct connection strings to both of them?

Comment: @szczocik update question,can you look at it one more time?

Comment: Where do you deploy it?

Comment: @szczocik I have ubuntu server and use apache and deploy it on /var/www/html

Comment: Right. I think it might be an apache configuration issue in that case. Make sure you have it setup correctly for node server and have ports open